# Call POST request to the REST API from Angular SPA

Tags: .net, angular, typescript

I have .Net Core Api with Angular SPA and I would like to invoke POST request to the REST API from Angular SPA without showing any component - it should be calling only http request. Could you tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your app-component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.post<string>("api/yourEndpoint", "Data to post, Type:<string>").subscribe(resonse=>console.log(resonse))
  }
}
```

ngOnInit is called when component is instantiated. There's doesn't have to be any content to display in app-component.html in order for this method to be called.

Please take a look at official documentation
https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request